# Jstl: format string number with spaces

Tags: java, jsp, format, jstl, string-formatting

I am looking for an implementation of the following:

I have a string: `001001001`
And I need to receive at the output: `001 001 001`

I checked the `formatNumber` and `DecimalFormat` - they can not provide such kind of output.
Is there any other built-in methods?

Currently I created some server-side function (that is actually not so brilliant solution I think):

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");

for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    result.append(input.charAt(i - 1));
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        result.append(" ");
}

return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the method below.
Does not add extra space at the end like in the example from nKognito.

```
public static String format(String inputUnformatted, int groupSize, String separator) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(inputUnformatted);

    int i = groupSize;
    while (i < inputUnformatted.length()) {
        result.insert(inputUnformatted.length() - i, separator);
        i += groupSize;
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "001001001";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (j > 2) {
                result.append(" ");
                j = 0;
            }

            result.append(input.charAt(i));
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());




    }
```

try this piece of code

Comment: My code works fine)) I just want to knowcan it be implemented via standard libraries like DecimalFormater, formatNumber or not...